# How to identify format of date in windows dir command?

Tags: windows, date, command-line, locale, dir

The dir command in Windows displays dates in a format that depends on operating system settings.

For example, when I run 'dir' from the command line on my computer, the date is displayed like '09/04/2015'.  When I run the same command on another server, I see '07/Aug/2015'.  I presume that many different formats are possible depending on operating system settings.

I need a way to reliably parse the day, month, and year from the date string returned by the 'dir' command, that will run on any Windows operating system since (and including) Windows XP.

Does anyone know how to force the 'dir' command to display dates in a particular format?

Or, does anyone know how to identify (from the command line) the format in which the 'dir' command will display dates?

Comment: Does this existing question and answer(s) help? [Windows 7 - How to get the Date in a batch file in a predictable format?](http://superuser.com/questions/315984/how-to-get-the-date-in-a-batch-file-in-a-predictable-format)

Comment: `date /t` will give you the current format.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  "date /t" on my system returns "Fri 09/04/2015" whereas the "dir" command returns only "09/04/2015".  How can I be sure that the two formats are related?

Comment: Double Click your right corner date settings->Change Date and Time->Change Calendar Settings->Additional Settings->go to Date Tab. Here you can see, that you can actually enter the custom format templates. So, to be sure of dir cmd date format, you actually have to force a format on user machine and then run the dir cmd.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Abhineet, I have confirmed that your suggestion works, but I need to be able to do this from the command line in an automated fashion.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I guess I can use the 'date /t' command to print a sample date, then test that against the formats available in the calendar settings popup window.  I do not know that the available date formats will be the same in all Windows versions however, so this method does not seem ideal.  I will leave my question open in the hope of finding a better or more direct method.

Answer (score 3):

> The solution is not perfect and I advise, not to implement it unless
>   very necessary.

When you change the format of date, it sets a registry value

> `HKCU\Control Panel\International`-> `sShortDate REG_SZ
>   <format_Of_date>` where format_of_date is the format chosen by user.

Now, if you edit this value to your convenient format and save it, the `dir` command will give you the expected format in result.

I said, it's not advisable because, changing custom settings on user machine is never good. To avoid this, what you can do is, store the initial value of `sShortDate` prior to changing and set that initial value after your implementation of `dir` cmd.

You can verify using this batch file::

```
reg export "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" C:\DateFormat.reg
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /f /v "sShortDate" /t 
REG_SZ /d "yyyy-MM-dd"
;; dir output always with "yyyy-MM-dd" date format
dir > C:\dir.txt
reg import C:\DateFormat.reg
del C:\DateFormat.reg
pause
```